# ffprobe output video: png

Tags: video, ffmpeg, file-format, ffprobe

ffprobe is telling me that my video file is a png.

```
[png_pipe @ 0x7f9ece003c00] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, png_pipe, from '1.ts':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1x1 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

[image]

I'm a little bit confused, as it plays fine as a ts or mpeg file. But when I run `ffmpeg -y -i in.ts -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4` the command completes fine, but I end up with a file that can't be played. I get an alert that says "The operation could not be completed" from Quicktime, and I can't open it in Chrome or Firefox either so I know it's not an issue with Quicktime.

So, this probably has to do with the video being a png video. I always thought that png was a format for images only, but here I am. Can someone give me some info on this, and how can I convert it to an mp4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, it could be a stream masqueraded with a PNG header.

I used dd to strip the 1st 8 bytes off and ffprobe detected the correct format.

```
dd if=1.ts of=fixed/1.ts ibs=8 skip=1
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Can you explain the encoding, because I'm still confused on why ffprobe returned png?

Answer (score 2):

By using `-vcodec copy`, you are storing the video as a PNG stream in a MP4. This is valid but not widely supported by players. Instead, encode it to a standard H.264 yuv420p pixels stream.

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.ts -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Edit:

The chunk is actually MPEG-TS but first 127 bytes appears to be a small PNG file affixed at the front. Forcing input format allows correct decoding.

So run,

```
ffmpeg -y -f mpegts -i in.ts -c copy out.mp4
```

Comment: It says invalid png signature https://i.imgur.com/P5Nw4Nm.png.

Comment: Does `ffplay in.ts` play the file?

Comment: No, I get the same invalid png signature.

Comment: Which player plays it?

Comment: Only Quicktime. Chrome and Firefox show a tiny white dot, that's not even a video (probably has to do with the png), and VLC is a 10 second video of a blank white screen. Interestingly, I tried multiple ones with different lengths in VLC, and all of them ended up being 10 seconds of nothing.

Comment: Which tool produced this video? And what info does QT show for it?

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood. When I run ffprobe in.ts it says video: png. So the input file, which I currently have as a ts file, is the main issue right now. Running ffprobe on out doesn't tell me png, it's the input file. I think the issue is that the file extension .ts is wrong and that I'm running the right command to convert to mp4. I'm still not really clear on how the png plays into this. I know the file definitely should not be in.png, that's just an image.

Comment: PNG is simply a codec. It is typically used to encode single images but can be used to encode a video stream. Which tool produced the input file? And what info does QT show for it?

Comment: cat. that's how someone said to concatenate them, and it worked, but there's probably a fancy ffmpeg version. Quicktime doesn't really show info, but it plays fine. Also, the ts files that were concatenated into in.ts also had the png encoding.

Comment: Then skip the TS file generation, and run `cat *.png | ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

Comment: Right now I have a few smaller ts chunks, that are concatenated into in.ts. So, I renamed those into png files, right, and ran that. I got `[png @ 0x7ffddb001000] Invalid PNG signature 0x9A6D9C624C4F62.` and `[libx264 @ 0x7ffddc81dc00] width not divisible by 2 (1x1)`.

Comment: Let's start from scratch. Share the result of one of these chunks: `ffmpeg -i chunk`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JjSXTcZ.png. Also, the image in the original post at the top is of `ffprobe chunk.ts`

Comment: Also, can you point me to some resources on this png encoding in videos? I've searched it up and haven't come up with much.

Comment: Can you share a couple of your chunks? I doubt they are actually PNG.

Comment: Can you send an article or some kind of source on the web on how this png encoding in videos works?

Comment: It works the same. The encoded PNG for each frame is stored as an individual packet.